# Asp.net 3.5 Sp1 Sub-Domain routing?

Tags: asp.net, wildcard-subdomain, asp.net-routing, webforms-routing

I was wondering is there is a way to introduce sub-domains in Asp.net 3.5 routing

All i found as this http://blogs.securancy.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx

But i was looking for something more complex to allow doing wild-card sub-domains

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be no problem, even with that sample. In this case, just add a wildcard to your DNS "*.yourdomain" and use the 'default' statement from the switch to handle wildcards.

In other words, change the sample for the Global.asax to something like:

```
                default: 
                returnValue = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                returnValue.Values.Add("controller", "MyControllerName"); 
                returnValue.Values.Add("action", "MyActionName");

                // for example, provide the entered subdomain as parameter;
                returnValue.Values.Add("MyActionParameterName", subDomain); 
                break;
```

And don't forget: add a wildcard to your DNS. It shall not be possible to test subdomains on localhost, though.

Comment: But i guess in that case the url will be something like this

http://example.yourdomain/MyControllerName/MyActionName/?MyActionParameterName=subDomain

Right ... which is the same point in the article i linked in my question

Comment: and if am right then there is no point of using the subdomain if i am passing it as a parameter.