# How to configure sub domains to asp.net mvc 3 areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am building an asp.net mvc 3 web application.
In my application I am using areas to separate my blog from my core website.
The blog is sitting in its own sub domain : blog.mysite.com

I'd like to map my area to the sub domain, how can this be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Areas in an ASP.Net MVC 2 Application map to a subdomain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047146/can-areas-in-an-asp-net-mvc-2-application-map-to-a-subdomain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this post as it should point you in the right direction.

[Can Areas in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application map to a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047146/can-areas-in-an-asp-net-mvc-2-application-map-to-a-subdomain)

or

http://forums.asp.net/t/1677286.aspx/1

Good luck

Comment: first result doesn't work with MVC 3 and second result doesn't work with areas

Comment: The first link seems like a general MVC routing example eventhough it says mvc2.  Is there a change to routing that isn't backwards compatible.  The second link was meant to be http://hanssens.org/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx.  There is no built in solution but overloading the routing with custom code will work.